# Динамический запрос к базе Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-jpa

Мне нужно сделать следующую вещь: пользователь вбивает различные критерии для поиска и по ним нужно найти строки в таблице, но запрос должен работать даже если часть данных не введены.
Условно, поиск можно осуществлять по промежутку между двумя датами, номером договора, наименованием плательщика и получателя. Но может быть заполнен только один из параметров. Или два и т.п, а остальные null.
Пожалуйста, подскажите, как это обработать средствами спринга

Comment: Вот тут в одной статья сразу 3 опции - CriteriaBuilder, Specifications и QueryDSL https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

Answer (score 0):

У меня возникли проблемы с подключением сторонних библиотек и я нашла вот такое решение. Проверила. По нему все работает. Очень удобно. Возьму на заметку и на будущее
https://russianblogs.com/article/2873392680/

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).